# Simple Python Random Module

Tags: python

I need to generate a random number between 0 and 7. but it must include decimals up to around 8 places. For example: 3.54367334 or 6.3464357. I haven't found anything in the random module that would give me something like that. Everything is with integers only, or from 0 to 1 (which is random.random).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could rescale `random.random`, why not use [random.uniform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) instead?

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.uniform(0, 7) for i in range(4)]
[3.36879678022553, 1.3262017420571945, 2.961415926838038, 6.409486371437773]
```

Answer (score 4):

As you noticed, [`random.random`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.random) returns a value in the range [0.0, 1.0). If you multiply its return value by 7, then the result will be in the range [0.0, 7.0).

There is also a function, [`random.uniform`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.uniform), which, given the range, will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
random.random() * 7
```

As `random.random` gives a number between 0 and 1.0, `* 7` will give between (0, 7.0)